# Basic Ajax implementation in Google App Engine

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-app-engine

I have been developing web applications on the Google App Engine for quite some time now, but this is my first time trying to implement Ajax in an application. Since I was familiar with Javascript concepts, I started with W3C's Ajax tutorial, and although I'm starting to get an idea of how Ajax is actually implemented, there's this one doubt that I need some help with.

I tried implementing the things I learned into a basic web application:

main.py

```
class AjaxHandler(Handler):
    def get(self):
        self.render("gg.html")    

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(('/ajax', AjaxHandler)], debug=True)
```

gg.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","aboutus.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

The 'aboutus.txt' file is saved inside my project directory. I don't know if my approach is correct, but I was expecting the default text in the 'gg.html' page to be replaced by the text inside my .txt file.

Now, I do understand that in the `xmlhttp.open("GET","aboutus.txt",true);` line, the 2nd parameter is the URL on which the file is stored on the server. Can someone point out what's wrong with my code ? And also provide the right way to change my default text on a webpage with the text provided inside a .txt file saved inside my project directory by using Ajax?